# How to see all layers of PDF document on iOS, specifically annotations

Tags: ios, pdf, layer

I'm working on an app for my company where we want to view annotations made on PDF documents in iOS (5.0).  The problem is that when the PDF document is viewed on iOS, whether in a UIWebView or QLPreviewer, the annotations do not appear.

I'm assuming that iOS is not picking up on a layer or "subView" of the PDF document. Does anyone know how to get these layers for the annotations to show up?

Comment: Edit: After more research I need more help. I'm basically trying to display the annotations made by iAnnotate or Adobe Reader for iOS. Every attempt to display it using Core Graphics or through a UIWebView have failed.  I know iOS is not picking up on the annotations attached to the PDF document.  Even using 3rd Party solutions like PSPDFKit or FastPDFKit won't show them.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to do this with the native iOS API for handling PDF documents. You will need to purchase a third-party solution that is better at properly reading PDF files.  [Here is one example](http://fastpdfkit.com/)

Comment: I was kinda afraid of that.  Thanks for the info :)